# Difference between `*mut [T]` and `*mut T`

Tags: pointers, rust

I noticed that `*mut [T]` has a [`len()` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.len). So it means that `*mut [T]` expects pointer to some memory location that contains both array length and the actual array, right? Therefore I cannot simply cast between the two types? Or is `*mut [T]` a fat pointer (so length is not stored behind the pointer but rather is part of the pointer)? Is this for example legal?

```
let l = Layout::array::<T>(size).unwrap();
let a = std::alloc::alloc(new_layout) as *mut [T];
```

or should I use `*mut T`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[T]` is a [dynamically sized type (DST)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/dynamically-sized-types.html). Pointers to DSTs are fat pointers that include the length, as you already suspected.
Your example (simplified to use `i32` instead of `T`)

```rust
fn main() {
    let l = std::alloc::Layout::array::<i32>(10).unwrap();
    let a = std::alloc::alloc(l) as *mut [i32];
}
```

[Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ee6fb8f719674c029d9bf40ab95e59a0)

will fail at compile time, with the following, very helpful error:

```rust
error[E0607]: cannot cast thin pointer `*mut u8` to fat pointer `*mut [i32]`
 --> src/main.rs:5:9
  |
5 | let a = std::alloc::alloc(l) as *mut [i32];
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0607`.
```

Which neatly proves this point.

---

An example to create a slice from a thin pointer could look like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let layout = std::alloc::Layout::array::<i32>(10).unwrap();
    let slice = unsafe { 
        let ptr = std::alloc::alloc(layout) as *mut i32;
        std::ptr::write_bytes(ptr, 0u8, 10); // initialize memory
        std::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, 10) 
    };
    println!("{:?}", slice);
}
```

[Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bc05bf8d1080d58c48ed2f913ae74d31)